# What is wrong with Module? or me?

Tags: programming, scoping

The following `code` does not give me an answer. It looks all is working when each command inside `Module` is individually run. But as a `Module`, it does not.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my formulation?

```
SeedRandom[02];

Gr = RandomGraph[{6, 10}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

sourceANDsinkF[G_, s_, t_] := Module[{e, source, sink},
   e      = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList[G]];
   source = Cases[e, s \[DirectedEdge] _];
   sink   = Cases[e, _ \[DirectedEdge] t]];
```

Comment: How do you call the function you have defined?

Comment: did you call the function? sourceANDsinkF[Gr,1,2] ??

Comment: @Mikado and @AliH: I call the function as `sourceANDsinkF[Gr, 1, 2]` for example.

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible [per OP's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183775/12).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's problem can not be reproduced and the OP indicates he now believes it was a local system issue.

Comment: Yes, it was an unknown problem with my computer. Now the same `Module` runs as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be also be interested in using the `IncidenceMatrix` matrix `A = IncidenceMatrix[Gr]` of the graph. This should be much more efficient.

One has `A[[i,j]] == 1` if edge `j` is ingoing into vertex `i`; `A[[i,j]] == -1` if edge `j` is outgoing from vertex `i`; and `A[[i,j]] == 0` if edge `j` otherwise.

So you get the sums of ingoing resp. outgoing edge weigths for *all* vertices at once as follows:

```
SeedRandom[2];

n = 6;
m = 10;
Gr = RandomGraph[{n, m},
   DirectedEdges -> True,
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[{1, 10}, m],
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"
   ];

outgoingweights = UnitStep[-IncidenceMatrix[Gr] - 1].PropertyValue[Gr, EdgeWeight]
ingoingweights = UnitStep[IncidenceMatrix[Gr] - 1].PropertyValue[Gr, EdgeWeight]
```

[image]

> {9, 11, 5, 14, 2, 6}
>
> {9, 10, 6, 8, 14, 0}

Comment: Your answer works very well, but I still want to know why I cannot use `Module` posted in my question, while everybody else can use it. Does it mean that `Mathematica 10` has a bug?

Comment: "Does it mean that Mathematica 10 has a bug?" Probably yes.

Comment: In your code, you find the sum of edge weights for all vertices. Is there a way to limit the sum of edge weights to a single `s' and a single `t'?

Comment: Of course: To the same with `IncidenceMatrix[Gr][[s]]` and `IncidenceMatrix[Gr][[t]]`, respectively. (This will work as long as you use integer values running from 1 to n as vertices. Otherwise, you have to compute the vertex indices first.)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ";" at the end of `Module[...]`, and it should work.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This `Module` works just fine, and nothing wrong with it. Apparently, there was internally something wrong with my computer. When I accidentally exited `Mathematica` and run it again, the above `code` started to work. So, as I suspected, there was something wrong on my side.